# Tumblr theme overriding post's text format

Tags: html, css, tumblr, tumblr-themes

Somehow my tumblr theme is overriding the formatting I have done to my texts posts (in html). It has decided to unbold everything that was bolded and make everything the same size, even though there was header text in the post. In tumblr itself you see it just like it was formatted to be seen, but in the tumblr theme (blog) everything appears the same format even though it isn't.

I know that there is a line of code inside of my theme overriding the formatting that has, but I have no clue where to find it or what to add to change it. If someone knows how I can change this I would appreciate the solution.

Maybe this is a little too basic but haven't found anything online about how to go around it.

Thanks in advance!

These images show [How it looks in Tumblr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFcvg.png) and [How it looks in the theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3bQq.png).

Comment: may i know how is your tumblr theme look like when it's overriding? any images or link.

Comment: How did you make the text big in the picture (inside Tumblr dashboard)? (example answer; used <h2> text </h2>) ?

Comment: Using <h2></h2>. Tumblr has an html editor, I usually work in that editor if i am doing something other than bolding the text. In other blogs (with another theme installed) I have changed the font color, used <h6> and other tags, and it has shown just fine, so I know is the theme that is overriding the formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the "Custom CSS". It should override any CSS applied to the theme.

1. Go to the theme customization page (looks like; "www.tumblr.com/customize/yourBlogName")
2. Scroll to the bottom of the Customization section in the left. Click the "Advanced Options" now paste your CSS under where it says "ADD CUSTOM CSS".

Example; `h2 { font-size: 1.5em; color: #6ca516 }`

If that does not work use `!important` (like; `font-size: 1.5em !important;`). Change the number in `font-size` and `color` as you want.

Note: 
It should override any CSS applied because in a Tumblr theme's HTML, `{CustomCSS}` (where all your "Custom CSS" goes) comes after all the other styles.

If you add your rules just before `</style>` in the theme's HTML, you will also override the styles applied before.

Comment: Ok so it works with the h2 tag, so tried doing something similar for the <b> tag and it doesn't seem to work. I wrote: b { font-weight: bold !important; } but it doesnt bold the text that is originally bolded. I'd like for the tag to remain being <b> since otherwise I'd have to manually change every post I have made.

Comment: Never mind, wrote it in the html code and it changed it. Thanks!

Comment: [Tumblr theme documentation](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_theme). Best wishes!